# How to expose node's container ports to network

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I created kubernetes cluster using rancher with 2 physical computers (Windows).

- master : `172.20.5.246`
- node : `172.20.5.227`

Once service is deployed via rancher server and when it also mapped to 81 of host as per below

[image]

I cannot access app via `172.20.5.227:81` ? Even I expose port via node's firewall

Comment: Can you please share how you created this service? Is there a yaml file that you could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: your service work internally meaning works if you check the service in the Master or in the Nodes and you got access to the service:

You need to change the service type to NodePort.
By doing so you will will expose the service external.

1. kubectl -n  edit service
2. Edit the file and change the type to NodePort (as the example:[image]

[image]

And than Browser to https://NODEIP:NODEPORT .